# Identifying conflicting extensions in classic Mac OS

Tags: classic-mac-os

I am experimenting with Sheepsaver and am having some problems. I've got it booting okay into Mac OS and have installed some games and other software. But I think I was a little too eager and installed too much without properly testing things and I'm experiencing a number of freezes. Actually, the screen freezes up and mouse pointer disappears but sound is still playing.

Anyway, I remember in the good old days having some software installed on my Power Macs that listed what extensions conflicted with what.

So, my questions are:

- What was that software?
- Is it still available?
- Does it work in sheepsaver?

Comment: [Conflict Catcher](http://www.macintoshrepository.org/653-conflict-catcher-9) is the one I remember.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, that's another utility we used a lot, although not as often once Apple incorporated the Extensions Manager into Mac OS (which I guess was the death knell for CC, especially since it was quite expensive).

Comment: @Tetsujin I remember Conflict Catcher too :) but InformINIT was what I was after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know exactly what you're talking about. It's called InformINIT and it was one of those tools that many of us Mac experts used to narrow down problems with. Even after Apple's Extensions Manager was released with Mac OS 7.5, InformINIT remained an extremely useful tool to identify those pesky control panels and extensions!

In summary:

- Yes, you can still download it from [here](http://www.mac.org/utilities/informinit/)
- Yes, it works within Sheepsaver!

As an aside, don't forget you can ask questions here about your Sheepsaver problems.